# Get values from one .each function into a different .each function

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, each

I have 4 sub-banners with `display: block; width: 100%;` that each have a div with text inside. These divs hangs down outside the parent element using `transform: translateY(238px)`.

Each div that holds the text is of varying height so I was trying to write a function to check each text div's height and apply the margin to the bottom of that specific parent element accordingly.

What I got so far is this, but I can't figure out how to get the variable `respectiveMargin` passed into my second each function so that it matches up with the right parent element. Right now it just applies the same margin on all sub-banners. Thanks for any and all help!

```
const resize = () => {

  if ($(window).width() < 768) {
    $('.sub-banner-text-wrapper').each(function () {
      var textHeight = $(this).height();
      var responiveMargin = (textHeight - 62) + 25;
    });

    $('.sub-banner').each(function () {
        $(this).css("margin-bottom", responiveMargin);
    });
  }

};
$(window).on('resize', resize);
```

Comment: What is the objective? Reading between the lines, you are trying to make all sub-banners have the same vertical height by adding a variable amount of margin. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems the main problem is that you're trying to use two `.each`es when you only need one:

```
const resize = () => {

  if ($(window).width() < 768) {
    $('.sub-banner-text-wrapper').each(function () {
      var textHeight = $(this).height();
      var responiveMargin = (textHeight - 62) + 25;

      $(this).closest('.sub-banner').css("margin-bottom", responiveMargin);
    });
  }

};
$(window).on('resize', resize);
```

Comment: Looks like there's a silent downvote bandit on the loose.

Comment: Jealous of our answers ;)

Comment: looks like we all posted almost the exact answer at the exact same time lol

Comment: Thank you so much! Cleared it up perfectly for me. I almost had it!

Answer (score 0):

So reference the index when you loop over the one set.

```
var banners = $('.sub-banner');
$('.sub-banner-text-wrapper').each(function (ind) {
  var textHeight = $(this).height();
  var responiveMargin = (textHeight - 62) + 25;
  banners.eq(ind).css("margin-bottom", responiveMargin);
});
```

If it happens to be a child/parent element, than you can just select it.

```
var banners = $('.sub-banner');
$('.sub-banner-text-wrapper').each(function (ind) {
  var textHeight = $(this).height();
  var responiveMargin = (textHeight - 62) + 25;
  //If a child
  $(this).find(".sub-banner").css("margin-bottom", responiveMargin);
  //or a parent
  $(this).parent().css("margin-bottom", responiveMargin);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Something like this?

```
if ($(window).width() < 768) {
        $('.sub-banner-text-wrapper').each(function () {
          var subBanner = $(this).closest('.sub-banner').attr('class');
          var textHeight = $(this).height();
          var responiveMargin = (textHeight - 62) + 25;
          $(subBanner).css("margin-bottom", responiveMargin);
        });
    }
```